# Am i proving right?

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Suppose that f is a function from A to B, where A and B are finite sets with |A| = |B|. Show that f is one-to-one if and only if it is onto.

First,i will prove that if function f is one-to-one then f is onto.

Premise

$1.f:A⇒B$

$2.|A|=|B|$

$3.x,y∈B,∀x∀y(f(x)=f(y)⇒(x=y))$

Proof by contradiction,

4.$c∈A,d∈B,∃d∀c(f(c)≠d)$

2,3,4 imples that there are at least a element belong to A that do not connect to B. Which contradict with 1.

So we proved if function f is one-to-one then f is onto.

After that,i will prove if f is onto then f is one to one.

Premise

$1.f:A⇒B$

$2.|A|=|B|$

$3.x∈A, y∈B, ∀y∃x(f(x)=y)$

Prove by contradiction,

4.$c,d∈B, ∃c∃d(f(c) =f(d) ∧ c≠d) $

2,3,4 also imple that there are at least a element belong to A that do not connect to B. Which contradict with 1.

Can we prove like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is sketchy. Saying $2,3,4$ provide a contradiction leaves the proof to the reader.

You don't need a proof by contradiction. We can show that $f$ is injective if and only if it is surjective by considering two cases:

1. $f$ is injective
2. $f$ is not injective

If $f$ is injective then $f$ maps each element of $A$ to a different point of $B$ so $f(A)$ consists of $|A|$ distinct points of $B$. Since $|B|=|A|$ there are only $|A|$ distinct points of $B$ so $f$ is surjective.

If $f$ is not injective then there exist points $a_1,a_2\in A$ such that $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$. Therefore $|f(A)|\lt |A|=|B|$ so $f$ is not surjective.